# Using parameter pack as typename for a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Is this valid: https://godbolt.org/z/_i9dwf

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Container
{
};

void fn()
{
    return;
}

template<typename T, typename...type_pack>
void fn(const Container<T>& head, const Container<type_pack>&... args)
{
    std::cout << "I am an " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    fn(args...);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    fn(Container<int>{}, Container<float>{});
    return 0;
}
```

Does C++ actually allow such expansions, or is this implementation defined based on compiler? I don't believe I have seen this type of syntax used elsewhere: `Container<type_pack>&...`. It's just something I came up with for what I wanted to achieve, and surprisingly it works. So my question is, is this UB, or is there an actual mention in the standard that this is well-defined?

Comment: It compile and print expected output with Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying a variable number of arguments, which are of a type `Container`, templated with types that will be used for deducing `type_pack`. For example, if you call:

```
fn(Container<int>{}, Container<float>{});
```

The `type_pack` will represent a `float` type. However, if you call:

```
fn(Container<int>{}, Container<float>{}, Container<int>{}, Container<std::string>{});
```

The `type_pack` will represent a parameter pack of `float, int, std::string`.

This behaviour is well defined by the standard.

Comment: This is precisely the behaviour I was looking for, I just didn't expect it to work I guess. Good to know that it's well defined in the standard.

Comment: @lightxbulb it's surprising what template parameter packs can do. For reference, take a look at [this amazing example](https://godbolt.org/z/xzWRBV). Here, the trick is by using a pack of `int`s, we initialize an `std::vector` of `std::function`s with `x` lambdas, where `x` is the size of the parameter pack and each lambda returns the corresponding element from the pack.

Comment: For once I am very pleasantly surprised while working with templates. Thank you for clarifying this and for the great lambda storage example.

Comment: Glad to see that yet another person fell into [the pit of success](https://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/) :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not?

In your code, `type_pack`

```
template<typename T, typename...type_pack>
void fn(const Container<T>& head, const Container<type_pack>&... args)
```

is in deduced context, so the compiler can deduce `float`, for `type_pack...`, from

```
fn(Container<int>{}, Container<float>{});
```